# App and app store is showing default language as Ukrainian. Need English

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, app-store-connect

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flowexpertpro/id571649995?ls=1&mt=8

In iTunes Connect, I have set the default language to UK English.

However, in the app store it shows the language as Ukrainian.

After I download the app, all the default commands (cut, copy, select  all) are also in Ukrainian. How can I set and keep it in UK English?

Comment: In the app what is your local development region set to. For UK English it should probably set to en_gb

Answer (score 3):

What is your *Localization native development region* inside .plist?

Must be:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en_GB</string>
```

for English.

Comment: He wants UK English specifically so it should be en_GB

Comment: I have uploaded with <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>. Lets see wether this has the effect.

Comment: but on thing I am unable to understand, why the language was set to Ukrainian, inside the app and itunes

Comment: It read the first two characters of UK English. UK. The two letter iso language code for Ukrainian is uk. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

Comment: i added UK English as default in itunes connect. and English as CGBundleDevelopmentRegion

Comment: The BundleDevelopmentRegion is what will throw it. Are you editing the plist directly or are you using the info screen for the project in Xcode? I ask because one way takes the language name, the other requires the ISO code.